# Autocalculated price field depending on language

Tags: entities

I need field for my own content type that will show price in currency depending on chosen language (from i18n module) calculated by currency exchange rate from currency module.

I've installed money field, but how to connect this to currency exchange?

I need some advice. I'm newbie.

Thanks for any hints, maybe I try to go wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed that with computed field. Money field was not needed.

In computed field I've posted code:

```
 $exchange_rate = CurrencyExchanger::load('PLN', 'EUR'); 
 $netto_price = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_name'))); 
 $entity_field[0]['value'] = bcmul($exchange_rate, $netto_price, 2);
```

It calculates currency in fly from currency module.